# Why Quarto PDF preview doesn't show LaTeX system of equations?

Tags: pdf, latex, jupyter, quarto

I'm using [Quarto](https://quarto.org/) tools to render my `ipynb` or `qmd` into PDF.
I typed in a system of equations in MD cell in `ipynb` file which looks fine in VS Code preview or `html` preview but cannot be rendered correctly in PDF preview.
Code in cell:

```
$$
\begin{cases}
  \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=a^2\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+2x,\;0<x<1\\
    u|_{x=0}=-2\\ u|_{x=1}=-1\\ u|_{t=0}=x-2
  
\end{cases}
$$
```

Cell preview within VS Code:

[image]

PDF output:

[image]

I assume my problem is with connecting MathJax to Quarto, but I didn't manage to find a way to do it. Do I need to install some libraries? Or adjust something in settings?

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace `$$` with `\begin{displaymath}` and `\end{displaymath}` as in:

```
\begin{displaymath}
  \begin{cases}
    \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=a^2\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+2x,\;0<x<1\\
      u|_{x=0}=-2\\ u|_{x=1}=-1\\ u|_{t=0}=x-2
  \end{cases}
\end{displaymath}
```

Then running:

```
quarto render my.ipynb --to pdf
```

will output a correct pdf file.

Read [Why is [ ... ] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to) to understand the reasons.